# using Activity with the support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_content_slider);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentFragment = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentFragment");
    }

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_content)).setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("content"));

    viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(viewPager);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, viewPager);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Simple"), NewsContent.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab"), NewsContent.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Create"), NewsContent.class, null);

}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
    private final Context context;
    private final ActionBar actionBar;
    private final ViewPager viewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }
    public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getFragmentManager());
        context = activity;
        actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        viewPager = pager;
        viewPager.setAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
```

I get an error on the line `super(activity.getFragmentManager());` because i am using the support library for FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

The error is:
FragmentStatePagerAdapter (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager) in FragmentSTatePagerAdapter cannot be applied to (android.app.FragmentManager)

If i change the line `public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager)` to `public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager)` then the error goes but i then get an error on the line `tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, viewPager);` due to a similar reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to use `ViewPager` with the framework provided `Fragment`s (i.e., `android.app.Fragment`), you can use the [support-v13 library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v13) which includes versions of [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) that support non-support Fragments.